# Ajax call to a different controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a different Controller method in an Ajax call.  I have looked at different posts for a solution but because I do not exactly understand what their solutions are (Links at bottom).  I am calling my ajax call from my Home Controller, trying to call a method in my Production Controller.

"Request URL: http://localhost.59223/Home/Production/CreateNewProductionGoal"

This is the error I am getting.

I have tried changing the **URL** to `.../Production/CreateNewProductionGoal and to ~/Production/CreateNewProductionGoal`, as suggested online.  Neither of these implementations worked because I was getting a **404 error, page not found**.

One of the linked solutions mentions using a loc var key, of which I am unfamiliar.

The other suggests using a button which is not an option in my case.

```
            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "Production/CreateNewProductionGoal",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,  //Creating a ProductionGoalViewModel to pass into the CreateNewProductionGoal method
            success: function (data) {
                //$('#Dashboard').load("/Home/UpdateView/" + selectProductionLine);
            }
        });
```

[Ajax call to different controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499643/ajax-call-to-different-controller)

[How to make ajax calls to different MVC controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329884/how-to-make-ajax-calls-to-different-mvc-controllers)

For clarification, I am looking for a step by step with explanation on how to Ajax call from one `MVC controller` to another.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should include a leading `/` in your url to call the correct URL:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    url: "/Production/CreateNewProductionGoal",
    ...
});
```

That way, the request will go to `http://localhost.59223/Production/CreateNewProductionGoal` instead.

The different paths, if you currently view `http://example.com/Home/`:

- `your/path`: This will take the current path as start path, i.e.  and add it to there, resulting in `http://example.com/Home/your/path`.
- `~/your/path`: can be used in asp.net server code, e.g. Razor to indicate the root of your website, only if it rendered. Browsers do not consider `~/` a special token, resulting in `http://example.com/Home/~/your/path` or `http://example.com/your/path`, when rendered
- `.../your/path`: nothing special, resulting in `http://example.com/Home/.../your/path`
- `../your/path`: go up one directory level, resulting in `http://example.com/your/path`. But this will result in different paths for nested directories.
- `/your/path`: absolute path, will always result in `http://example.com/your/path`, independently of nested directories.

For more on absolute and relative URL see [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: Thank you.  What is the difference between ~/, .../ and just /?

Answer (score 1):

This might still be helpful for someone to use

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    url: "@string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"))/Production/CreateNewProductionGoal",
    ...
});
```